# How to get element by ID in php DOMDocument class?

Tags: php, class, domdocument

I am trying to parse a HTML file using DOMDocument class in PHP.
The sample HTML file is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="myparagraph"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I loaded it using

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtmlFile("page.html");
```

Now I try to get the p element by id this way

```
print_r($document->getElementById("myparagraph"));
```

This doesn't work for some reason. So what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Do you have a DOCTYPE? If not, it will always return NULL.

Comment: Evan that worked ! Thanks a lot :D, I added a doctype and now it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) getElementById doesn't really work that well.  What you can do is create your own function similar to this:

```
function getElementById($id)
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->domDocument);
    return $xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0);
}
```

With thanks to paradox_haze who posted the information in the comments on the PHP docs.